# Why isn't my ajax code updating my second dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have no idea why my code isn't working. I basically have two dropdowns, the first is populated from an mssql database and I want the second dropdown to update dependant on the selection in the first.

Below is my code which populates a dropdown box:

```
<?php
session_start();
$serverName = "REDACTED";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"REDACTED", "UID"=>"REDACTED", "PWD"=>"REDACTED");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if (!isset($_SESSION['nID']))
{
    header("Location: Login.php");
    die();
}

function loadRegion()
{
    include 'config.php';
    $output = '';
    $regionQuery = 'select distinct id, region from regionsHaiss order by id';
    $regionPopulate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $regionQuery, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($regionPopulate))
    {
        $output .= "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['ID'])."\">".$row['region']."</option>";
    }
    return $output;
}
?>
```

I then use this to populate the first dropdown:

```
<p>Select a Region
<select name ="region" id ="region">
<option value ="">Select Region</option>
<?php echo loadRegion(); ?>
</select></p>
```

For the second dropdown box I have the following:

```
<p>Select a Territory
<select name="territory" id="territory">
<option value="">Select Territory</option>
</select></p>
```

I call my ajax via:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("ready");
    $('#region').change(function(){
        var region_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"getter.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{regionId:region_id},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#territory').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My getter page reads as follows:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'config.php';

$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT distinct id,territory,rid FROM territoriesHaiss where RID = '".$_POST["regionId"]."' order by id";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
$output = '<option value ="">Select Territory</option>';

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['ID'])."\">".$row['territory']."</option>";
    }

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: It looks basically right to me. Are there any errors in the Javascript console? If you look in the Network tab, do you see it making the AJAX call, and does the response look correct? These are all basic debugging steps you should take before posting here.

Comment: `$row['ID']` should probably be `$row['id']`, since you use the lowercase column name in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to debug this effectively as I don't normally code in these languages. How can I check if the AJAX call is being made correctly?

Comment: do a `console.log(data)` in the response part of your ajax call to `getter.php` see what your browser console has to say

Comment: Open Developer Tools (F12), go to the Network tab, then select something from the menu. You should see the AJAX call, and you can then click on it to see the details, including the parameters that are sent and the response that's received.

Comment: When I add the console.log(data) step the console repeatedly shows '<option value ="">Select Territory</option>', so does this mean the php is being returned correctly but my ajax isn't sending the id correctly? @KenziieeFlavius

Comment: Check the HTML of the original Region menu, make sure all the `value="xxx"` are filled in correctly.

Comment: I suspect that script is not filling them in because it uses `$row['ID']` instead of `$row['id']`.

Comment: You should also enable PHP warnings with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script. Then you'd see the warnings about these undefined indexes.

Comment: @Barmar I've changed the getter.php script to use the lower case id but it still doesn't seem to be working. I'm having a look into the HTML now to see if I can find anything there

Comment: I appreciate the help guys. I'm trying to use the console in browser now to see what exactly is being sent by ajax to the getter.php script

Comment: Did you also change the script that populates the Regions menu?

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was the id in the regions script I completely overlooked that. It's working now! Thanks again for the help I never would have discovered that on my own

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the 2 comments above (thanks again for the help!) the error was in the code that populates the first dropdown. It should have been a lowercase 'ID', like follows:

```
function loadRegion()
{
    include 'config.php';
    $output = '';
    $regionQuery = 'select distinct id, region from regionsHaiss order by id';
    $regionPopulate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $regionQuery, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($regionPopulate))
    {
        $output .= "<option value=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['id'])."\">".$row['region']."</option>";
    }
    return $output;
}
?>
```